# Layout manager for .NET, UI agnostic

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, layout

I need a simple Layout Manager that is UI agnostic. By this, I mean it should not specify how I want to represent my shapes/controls on the screen. It should just enable me to say:

I want shape X here.
I want shape Y under shape X.
I want shape Z to surround X, and isolate itself from shape Y.

I guess it would be nice if it can also give me (X, Y) for each shape when I am finished.

I am using .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider Windows Presentation Foundation

[The Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx)